# Select todos los registros excepto uno específico

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un aside con artículos relacionados a mi artículo principal. El problema es que en esos artículos relacionados también me aparece el principal.

Es posible seleccionar todos los registros de mi tabla artículos menos el que yo señale?

Comment: La consulta puede ser : `SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE id <> idarticuloprincipal;` que retornará los artículos menos el que tenga el id pasado a la consulta.

Comment: El comentario por @Dev.Joel es el correcto. Solo que deberías adjuntar el código con el cual intentaste hacer la consulta, para así poderte ayudar de una mejor forma. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM ARTICULOS 
WHERE IDARTICULO <> 'ARTICULO_PRINCIPAL'
```

Eso fue lo que entendi, Espero y te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto

```
select *from articulos where id_articulo not in (3);
```

Comment: Javier, asegúrate de responder a preguntas bien formadas, tal como lo indica la guía: [_Cómo responder_](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). En cualquier caso, cuida que tu respuesta cumpla con las características de [__una respuesta aceptable__](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/958/).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM MITABLA WHERE IDARTICULO != MIIDPRONCIPAL
```

Con esto lo tienes si conoces el id del principal o un valor que lo diferencie. si necesitas una ayuda más específica deberías dar alguna idea de la estructura  de tu base de datos o del proceso para diferenciarlo si es por código `PHP`.